# Elasticsearch : Need advice on architectural design of my cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new to elasticsearch. I need to build a search system using the data from MongoDB. So, here is a high level overview of my application:

- There are different users belonging to different organizations
- A User can upload multiple datasets. Each dataset is stored as a single document in MongoDB. However, each dataset contains an array of nodes which contain the data we are interested in.
- User can load one dataset at a time to his workspace and view the entire data for that particular dataset. But at a time, one user can view only one dataset. So, datasets are independent from each other and we never need to have any aggregation on multiple datasets.
- User can perform a search in a dataset which is loaded in his/her workspace. Search should return the matching elements from the nodes array of the dataset

For illustration, here is a single doc in MongoDB datasets collection

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId()
  "setName": "dummy_set",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": ObjectId(),
      "label": "some text",
      "content" : "more text"
    },
    . . . 
  ]
}
```

For this, the design that I have though about is:

- There will be one index in my cluster
- Each single dataset will be stored in a separate type in the index. Name of the type will be the ObjectId of the dataset in mongoDB
- Each element in the nodes array of dataset will become a single document in the corresponding type in elasticsearch.
- I will use custom routing to make sure a single dataset resides on one shard only. For that, I will be using the type name (ObjectId of dataset from MongoDB) as my routing key. I assume, I will have to store it with each document in elasticsearch?

Now I need to know if I am heading in a right direction ? Does the solution look scalable or is there something terribly wrong with the design and would love to hear some suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Why are you using custom routing? It seems like premature optimization. Any idea how large these datasets will be? How many datasets will there be? Having multiple shards gives you high availability, and the option to scale out. If you want to scale horizontally you may want a dataset on more than a single shard. Also you should consider you'll have a shard per dataset, so if you have 200 datasets that's 200 shards. And shards get a portion of that nodes resources. That's definitely not sustainable, nor scalable.

Comment: I am not considering one shard per dataset. I suppose multiple datasets can reside on same shard in the design I proposed above. Its just that one dataset will not get distributed on different shards and in my opinion that does scale very well horizontally since a search will be focused on one shard. I hope I am not missing something conceptually ?

Comment: If you're planning to scale by the number of shards/datasets you have then your approach makes sense, but sounds expensive. You're going to end up either paying a lot for all these hosts, or overallocating shards. Then again that depends on how many datasets you have. Are you planing on having replica's of these shards? Otherwise you're sacraficing high availability, however then you're worsening the issue. I just don't see any reason to allocate a type to a single shard. Is the performance you experience poor otherwise?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that a single shard on a single node means that only that shard can perform operations on that dataset. So if you have a dataset that is getting more "attention" than the others then you'll have a single node that's taking the brunt of the traffic. Additionally note that a shard is allocated a given amount of resources of the node its allocated to. So you're only using a fraction of a single node to perform most of your operations. This means poor elasticity, unless all datasets will be queried almost equally.

Comment: Another problem. Each shard isn't going to be a uniform size, so you'll quickly find that the shards allocated to each host will be odd, and uneven. Again making it hard to leverage the resources at hand.

Comment: I agree that some datasets might be queried more and some might be queried less. But to think that all those datasets will fall on single shard seems unreasonable to me. Also to your point about each shard being not a uniform sized, I think that is more of a concern with the routing value. Since I will be using MongoDB's ObjectId which is fairly random, then it should ensure that distribution will be random as well. What do you think ?

Comment: If you're going to have each dataset on a different shard, it was my idea that you were using routing to accomplish this. So I don't see how that would make it random. Also do not put your data on one shard. What I'm saying is that I don't see any reason to use routing, just let elasticsearch handle sharding. I have a repl set of 2 nodes, with 5 shards on each, they handle 5million documents. I can run a query, score it, and get results in 300-500ms. I doubt you'll run into performance issues.

Comment: The problem is your complicating things more than they need to be. What exactly is routing for, other than performance? How exactly are you assuring equal, or _equal enough_, shard size? ElasticSearch will handle partitioning your data into shards on its own, and its pretty efficient. If you're concerned about over allocation, and the overhead of shards, you can allocate a smaller number of shard. Its possible to later reindex to an index with more shards if you require it for scaling. You're idea is otherwise sound, I just don't understand why you're using routing.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, its not exactly best practice to start out with too few shards, but its not going to break anything. It'll likely just be a pain later on.

Comment: thanks for the discussion. I will keep the defaults for now since its gonna take a lot of time for the number of documents to rise up to even 1 million. When I run to performance issues, I will do some analysis and compare the two approaches and evaluate how random the distribution is with my approach. However, I was going to start with 5 shards which would keep filling as and when datasets arrived. For too few datasets, there will be skew in my approach but I believe as the number of docs increase, it would even out since the routing is quite random. Still I will stick to defaults for now